# What is the difference between webpack.config.js And Webpack.mix.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I'm new at webpack but I'm working with laravel and i see webpack.mix.js, so what is the difference between it and webpack.config.js, is there any functions that's I'll miss in webpack.mix?

Comment: Hmm, the Laravel applications I'm working with (Laravel 6.x and Laravel 8.x) don't have `webpack.config.js`, only `webpack.mix.js`. Do you know when it got added?

Comment: Nope it's not added but i wanted to know if there's any different between them

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`webpack.config.js` is just a service file. Laravel Mix based on Webpack so you don't need to touch it.

Comment: Thank you! You mean that I don't have to edit anything in laravel mix and i can install webpack beside laravel mix and work with it right?

Comment: You can, but why? Laravel Mix was created for work with Webpack by easier way.

Comment: Also Webpack already installed.